# Prove the Relations

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $\operatorname{ord}(a \mid n)$ denote the order of $a$ modulo $n$. Given $\operatorname{ord}(a \mid n)$ and $\operatorname{ord}(b \mid n)$ find $\operatorname{ord}(ab \mid n)$ and $\operatorname{ord}(\operatorname{lcm}$ $(a,b) \mid n)$.

I have tried to approach it in the following lines.

> We get $(ab)^{\operatorname{ord}(a \mid n)} \equiv b^{\operatorname{ord}(a \mid n)}$ $(\operatorname{mod}$ $n)$. Hence the order of $b^{\operatorname{ord}(a \mid n)}$ should be equal to the order of $(ab)^{\operatorname{ord}(a \mid n)}$. But we have ${\operatorname{ord}(b^{\operatorname{ord}(a \mid n)} \mid n)}$ $=$ $\dfrac{\operatorname{ord}(b \mid n)}{\operatorname{gcd}(\operatorname{ord}(a \mid n),\operatorname{ord}(b \mid n))}$.

But from that I can't proceed. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The orders of $a$ and $b$ need not determine the order of $ab$, unless these orders are relatively prime.

For example, let $n=5$.  If $a=b=2$, then each of $a$ and $b$ has order $4$, and $ab$ has order $2$. But if $a=2$ and $b=3$, each has order $4$ but the product has order $1$.

Comment: When these orders are relatively prime what will be the order of $ab$? Can you give a proof?